# How to add a onItemclicklistener method to recycleview of buttons

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, syntax

I want to make a onItemclicklistener method to recycleview of buttons and every button intent to Activity 
but the Activity has Textview (every button has different Textview )

```
public class RecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

            Button button;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonn);
            }
        }

        private Context context;
        private List<items> items;

        public RecAdapter(Context c, List<items> itemList) {
            this.context = c;
            items = itemList;
        }

        @Override
        public RecAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.buttonss, parent, false);

            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            items p = items.get(position);
            holder.button.setText(p.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return items.size();
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnClickListener` on `itemView` of `holder` like below:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    items p = items.get(position);
    holder.button.setText(p.getName());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Do here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @HamzaKhalifa, if this help you then please accept the answer

Comment: i cannot because i am new but i will do it when i can